# Where do I get extra Compiz plugins?

Tags: compiz, plugins

I installed Compiz on my laptop running Ubuntu 11.10 last week. The way I installed it was kind of different, I opened up a terminal and typed this command:

```
    sudo apt-cache search compiz
```

After that, I installed all the packages that appeared in the terminal window. I enjoyed all the effects of Compiz like Paint fire on screen, Desktop Cube, but I can't help  but noticing people having some extra plugins which I don't have, such as Atlantis, Snow, Tile and much more.

Where are they getting all those plugins and how do I get them?

Comment: Why 'sudo'? It worked without for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [compiz wiki plugins](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins) to learn about all plugins, including ones not added by default in CCSM and other compiz configuration tools.

Also look at [wiki entrance](http://wiki.compiz.org) under "Installing Compiz" for installation information and to understand differences in core compiz.

Answer (score 3):

Go to terminal then type the following:

For Older Ubuntu versions:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
```

In Ubuntu 12.10:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of those plugins are no longer supported or developed, and were only available in older versions of Ubuntu. Tile and Snow may still be available, possibly atlantis, but for the most part many of the "useless candy" plugins are no longer maintained.